# Firebase Realtime Database set() and push() not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Everything is working great except when I try to write to my database. The web page reads and deletes successfully.

Both read and write rules are set to true. this is how I set up firebase:

```
<script>

   // Initialize Firebase
   var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyA5fulcW9C8xxmo5UeeS3khTrYCW4yMpKI",
      authDomain: "some-app.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://some-app.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "some-app",
      storageBucket: "some-app.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "870590230527"
   };

   firebase.initializeApp(config);


</script>
```

And here is the app.js file. There are 3 attempts at writing data to the database which all failed. Nothing was added and no errors were returned. The reading and deleting works fine which means that I have firebase set up correctly. The set() attempt is straight from the Firebase docs. I only want to add a new entry in "articles" with a generated ID, which has a title, author, and text property. That's it.

```
var database = firebase.database();


firebase.database().ref('articles/' + randKey.toString()).set({
        title: title_,
        author: author_,
        text: text_
});
```

Comment: How do you set your Firebase config?

Comment: There's too much going on here: a query, multiple attempts to write, and some potentially irrelevant retrieval of values from the HTML. Can you reproduce the problem in a single, standalone piece of code of no more than a dozen lines or so. The *standalone* part is key here, since that allows any of us to simply copy/paste your code to (try to) reproduce the problem. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just updated the question. Should be clearer now.

Comment: try using firebase.database.ref(...).set(...).then(ok => console.log("worked")).catch(console.error) and see what happens

Comment: I added your promise and it did not catch any errors. I played around with it and no errors are returned at all. The set() is working according to Firebase, but with no additions or changes to the database.

Comment: Are you then getting something in the "resolved" block? Are you reading "worked" on the console, or is there absolutely nothing printing out?

Comment: reading 'worked' and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Should not have posted this before testing because the set() is working and what was crashing it was title_, author_, and text_ which did not contain String values.